# How can I update my List in my main JFrame from a database after closing a the window I use to update the db info

Tags: java, windowlistener

I would like the list box in my main window to update once I close the window I am using to update a database. The window listener I have set up works. I previously used it to trigger a message box. So at this point I just need it to update the list in the Jframe.

This is what I am using to open the window to edit the db and then the listener fro when it closes

```
DBList edit = new DBList();
    edit.setVisible(true);
    edit.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);

    edit.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){

            displayAllProducts();

        }
        });
```

my displayAllProductsMethod

```
public void displayAllProducts()
{   

    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    listBooks = new JList(listModel);

    ProductDB prod = new ProductDB();
    Product listProd = new Product();
    ArrayList <Product> products = prod.getProducts();

    for(Product p : products)
        listModel.addElement(p.toString());

    return;



}
```

originally I have it load into the list box like so

```
list = new JList(listModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

And what is wrong with 
`list.getModel()`?. At this point you will have access to every list element so you can modify it to suit your needs. You can always create new List model and then call `list.setModel(newUpdatedModel)`. Just remember to do that on the EDT for example using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` so the GUI will update.

Comment: okay I went ahead and added that, it still does not update the list when the  frame is closed

Comment: edit.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   
            Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
             
             displayAllProducts();
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
     
     @Override
     public void run() {
      displayAllProducts();
      list.setModel(listModel);
      
     }
    } );
             
            }
            });

Comment: @paxtuik you should rather update your post insteed of pasting code in the comments as it is barely readable. Anyway, your `displayAllProducts` is creating new `JList` everytime, it is not adding it to the GUI, and returns nothing so my guess is that some other part of the code is placing that particular list on the GUI. In this case, you are simply creating new list but not showing it at all (old one is displayed) as changing the VALUE OF THE FIELD, will not change GUI references.